# C++/CLI Dll with C# Connection problem

Tags: c#, c++, dll, c++-cli

I have 3 projects in one solution.

I have :

- a native C++ dll,
- a C# Winform,
- and a proxy C++/CLI without pure mode to do the link between the 2 others projects (and use the native function in the managed code in C#)

So when I launch the application all work. But when I push the button "Generer" in my winform wich execute the function *NativeMethod::Test()* of the C++/CLI that it crash and I have this pop-up message :

> An unhandled exception of type
> 'System.BadImageFormatException'
> occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load
> file or assembly
> 'EngineInterfaceWrapper.dll' or one of
> its dependencies.  n'est pas une
> application Win32 valide. (Exception
> from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)

When I go in project proprieties in Conf. Properties -> Linker -> Advanced : Target Machine, it's set with the value "MachineX86" for my C++ native and managed DLL and my WinForm is in X86 too. I tired many configurations but it don't work.

Edit:

The problem is may be the header "TradeEngine.h"" in the C++/CLI header : EngineInterfaceWrapper.h. Because when I unlink the native C++ Dll (and deleting all code in the CLI wrapper) if I build the solution it will work but if "#include "TradeEngine.h"" is always in the CLI header, I will have the same error. Do you have an idea?

Code :

**native C++**

TradeEngine.h

```
#ifdef TRADEENGINE_EXPORTS
#define SYMBOL_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#define SYMBOL_DEF
#else
#define SYMBOL_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllimport)
#define SYMBOL_DEF      __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

EXTERN_C SYMBOL_DECLSPEC void __stdcall Test(void);
```

TradeEngine.cpp

```
SYMBOL_DECLSPEC void __stdcall Test(void)
{
}
```

**C++/CLI**

EngineInterfaceWrapper.h

```
#pragma once

#include "TradeEngine.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace EngineInterfaceWrapper {

    public ref class NativeMethod
    {
    public:
        static void AjoutColonneDifferenceCourtClotureOuvertureReelle(void);
        static void Test();
    };
}
```

EngineInterfaceWrapper.cpp

```
#pragma region Includes
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "EngineInterfaceWrapper.h"
using namespace EngineInterfaceWrapper;

#include <msclr/marshal.h>
using namespace msclr::interop;
#pragma endregion

void NativeMethod::Test()
{
    ::Test();
}
```

**C# Winform**

Program.cs

```
namespace TradeInterface
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

generer_Click() is the event launched by the button when the user click on Generer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using EngineInterfaceWrapper;

namespace TradeInterface
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void generer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NativeMethod.Test();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix that? If you need more info, tell me.

Comment: Is natice C++ Dll available when client project is executed? It should be in the current, exe, system directory or available through PATH.

Comment: All Work when I launch my WinForm. All stuff are in the same Debug folder. It crash when I push my button which launch Test().

Comment: Does it work if NativeMethod::Test doenlt call ::Test?

Comment: Also, does it work if EngineInterfaceWrapper.dll is not linked to native dll? Try to isolate the problem.

Comment: No it crash with the same pop-up message. The problem is I don't know C# and CLI so it's really hard for me. :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason can be you are trying to load a native 32-bit dll in a 64-bit process. Make sure you have platform target set to `x86` in your app to force your application to run inside WoW64.

Comment: I added more information, I set all project in x86 and I have always the same problem.

Comment: @Nazka: Are both the C# and C++/CLI projects built with the same version of .NET?

Comment: @Ben Voigt All work with the v4.0. We can see V4.0XXXX or not?

Answer (score 8):

I have found the solution :

http://marc.info/?l=boost-users&m=123425857320026

> In Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor
>   Definitions add BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK in order to  force the usage of the
>   DLLs. In addition copy the necessary DLLs to the directory where the 
>   executable resides.  E.g. copy boost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_XX.dll  to
>   MyApp/bin/Debug.